# GetClipboardSequenceNumber() function declaration

Tags: c++, keylogger

I want to capture clipboard copy & cut address in c++ but compiler says there is a error that GetClipboardSequenceNumber() function is not declaration. how I can declare that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <winuser.h>
using namespace std; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   DWORD y = GetClipboardSequenceNumber();
   while(1) {
        Sleep(1000);
        if(y!=GetClipboardSequenceNumber()) 
             {
               OpenClipboard(NULL);
               HANDLE X =GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
               cout<<(char*)GlobalLock(X);
               GlobalUnlock(X);
             }
           }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using API call specific to an operating system (I'm guessing Windows). Please amend your tags appropriately. Please also indent your code properly.

Comment: yes I am using windows 7. can you give me correct code

Comment: No, but someone else might be able to if you set the appropriate tags on your post.

Answer (score 0):

This likely depends on the compiler but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states this is only available for Windows 2000 and newer so you should ensure that you declared the right WINVER version to obtain access to the necessary functions. ie: #define WINVER 0x0501 before you include Windows.h gets it to include functions that are defined for XP but not functions that only became available in Windows Vista (0x600). If you use Visual C++ then the Platform SDK tends to define a sensible value. But to be certain - define both WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT before you include any windows headers.

Comment: my compiler is Dev c++ and my os is win 7 32 bit. that work you said does not work. please tell me what can I do